# weird ansible behaviour when trying to remove files

Tags: ansible

I have the following step in my playbook to remove some unwanted default configuration files while leaving backups just in case:

```
- name: remove some shibboleth config files if present
  shell: "mv {{ item }} {{ item }}.orig"
  loop:
    - /etc/shibboleth/attrChecker.html
    - /etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml
    - /etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml
    - /etc/shibboleth/example-shibboleth2.xml
  when: item is file
```

The output is the following:

```
TASK [backend : remove some shibboleth config files if present]
****************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.60.28] => (item=/etc/shibboleth/attrChecker.html)
failed: [192.168.60.28] (item=/etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mv /etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml /etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml.orig", "delta": "0:00:00.006012", "end": "2019-05-13 13:28:51.886074", "item": "/etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-13 13:28:51.880062", "stderr": "mv: stat '/etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml' sikertelen: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár", "stderr_lines": ["mv: stat '/etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml' sikertelen: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
failed: [192.168.60.28] (item=/etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mv /etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml /etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml.orig", "delta": "0:00:00.005486", "end": "2019-05-13 13:28:52.205756", "item": "/etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-13 13:28:52.200270", "stderr": "mv: stat '/etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml' sikertelen: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár", "stderr_lines": ["mv: stat '/etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml' sikertelen: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
skipping: [192.168.60.28] => (item=/etc/shibboleth/example-shibboleth2.xml)     to retry, use: --limit @/home/pallinger/mtmt2/install/ansible/all.retry
```

So it seems it realizes that two of the files are not there, but it fails to realize that the other two aren't there either! In reality, none of them are there:

```
root@192.168.60.28:~# ls -l /etc/shibboleth/attrChecker.html /etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml /etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml /etc/shibboleth/example-shibboleth2.xml
ls: cannot access '/etc/shibboleth/attrChecker.html': No such file or directory 
ls: cannot access '/etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/etc/shibboleth/example-shibboleth2.xml': No such file or directory
```

**Does anyone know a possible fix for this behaviour?**

I tried putting all loop values in quotes and changing the item order in the loop, but the result is always the same: `attrChecker.html` and `example-shibboleth2.xml` are recognized to be absent, while the other two are not.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realised what I did wrong: the `when: item is file` line checks for *local* files, while I wanted to check for *remote* files. The below variant solves the problem using the `removes` directive for the command module:

```
- name: remove some shibboleth config files if present
  command: removes="{{ item }}" "mv {{ item }} {{ item }}.orig"
  loop:
    - /etc/shibboleth/attrChecker.html
    - /etc/shibboleth/example-shibboleth2.xml
    - /etc/shibboleth/protocols.xml
    - /etc/shibboleth/security-policy.xml
```